# Are typedef and #define the same in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, typedef

I wonder if `typedef` and `#define` are the same in C. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

No.

`#define` is a preprocessor token: the compiler itself will never see it.
`typedef` is a compiler token: the preprocessor does not care about it.

You can use one or the other to achieve the same effect, but it's better to use the proper one for your needs

```
#define MY_TYPE int
typedef int My_Type;
```

When things get "hairy", using the proper tool makes it right

```
#define FX_TYPE void (*)(int)
typedef void (*stdfx)(int);

void fx_typ(stdfx fx); /* ok */
void fx_def(FX_TYPE fx); /* error */
```

Comment: After the typedef `stdfx`, valid objects of that type are pointers to functions that receive an int and do not return a value.

Comment: Why would the #define fail in casec of function pointer as argument?

Comment: @Allahjane: the expansion becomes `void fx_def(void (*)(int) fx);`; the correct declaration is `void fx_def(void (*fx)(int));`.

Comment: Function pointers are doable with macros, only if you're ready to give up syntax: `#define FX_TYPE(f) void (*f)(int)`. You'd then declare your function as: `void fx_def(FX_TYPE(fx));`

Answer (score 259):

`typedef` obeys scoping rules just like variables, whereas `define` stays valid until the end of the compilation unit (or until a matching `undef`).

Also, some things can be done with `typedef` that cannot be done with `define`.
For example:

```
typedef int* int_p1;
int_p1 a, b, c;  // a, b, c are all int pointers

#define int_p2 int*
int_p2 a, b, c;  // only the first is a pointer, because int_p2
                 // is replaced with int*, producing: int* a, b, c
                 // which should be read as: int *a, b, c
```

```
typedef int a10[10];
a10 a, b, c;  // create three 10-int arrays
```

```
typedef int (*func_p) (int);
func_p fp;  // func_p is a pointer to a function that
            // takes an int and returns an int
```

Answer (score 28):

No, they are not the same.  For example:

```
#define INTPTR int*
...
INTPTR a, b;
```

After preprocessing, that line expands to

```
int* a, b;
```

Hopefully you see the problem; only `a` will have the type `int *`; `b` will be declared a plain `int` (because the `*` is associated with the declarator, not the type specifier).

Contrast that with

```
typedef int *INTPTR;
...
INTPTR a, b;
```

In this case, both `a` and `b` will have type `int *`.

There are whole classes of typedefs that cannot be emulated with a preprocessor macro, such as pointers to functions or arrays:

```
typedef int (*CALLBACK)(void);
typedef int *(*(*OBNOXIOUSFUNC)(void))[20]; 
...
CALLBACK aCallbackFunc;        // aCallbackFunc is a pointer to a function 
                               // returning int
OBNOXIOUSFUNC anObnoxiousFunc; // anObnoxiousFunc is a pointer to a function
                               // returning a pointer to a 20-element array
                               // of pointers to int
```

Try doing that with a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 14):

[**#define**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) defines macros.
**[typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)** defines types.

Now saying that, here are a few differences:

With **#define** you can define constants that can be used in compile time. The constants can be used with **#ifdef** to check how the code is compiled, and specialize certain code according to compile parameters.
You can also use **#define** to declare miniature find-and-replace **[Macro functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc09cpxmac.htm)**.

**typedef** can be used to give aliases to types (which you could probably do with **#define** as well), but it's safer because of the find-and-replace nature of **#define** constants.
Besides that, you can use **[forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)** with **typedef** which allows you to declare a type that will be used, but isn't yet linked to the file you're writing in.

Comment: what do you mean by find and replace nature of #define ? , Thank you

Comment: It means before compilation, preprocessor will find all macros and replace them with their original syntax

Comment: "typedef can be used to give aliases to types " This explained the purpose for me, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Preprocessor macros ("`#define`'s") are a lexical replacement tool a la "search and replace". They are entirely agnostic of the programming language and have no understanding what you're trying to do. You can think of them as a glorified copy/paste mechanic -- occasionally that's useful, but you should use it with care.

Typedefs are a C language feature that lets you create aliases for types. This is extremely useful to make complicated compound types (like structs and function pointers) readable and handlable (in C++ there are even situations where you *must* typedef a type).

For (3): You should always prefer language features over preprocessor macros when that's possible! So always use typedefs for types, and constant values for constants. That way, the compiler can actually interact with you meaningfully. Remember that the compiler is your friend, so you should tell it as much as possible. Preprocessor macros do the exact opposite by *hiding* your semantics from the compiler.

Comment: Can you tell one example in C++ where you must typedef a type? I'm just curious about that.

Comment: @jyzuz: There's something if you want a member function to return an array of function pointers, or something like that -- if you try to spell out the type, GCC actually says "you must use a typedef".

Answer (score 4):

They are very different, although they are often used to implement custom data types (which is what I am assuming this question is all about).

As pmg mentioned, `#define` is handled by the pre-processor (like a cut-and-paste operation) before the compiler sees the code, and `typedef` is interpreted by the compiler.

One of the main differences (at least when it comes to defining data types) is that `typedef` allows for more specific type checking.  For example,

```
#define defType int
typedef int tdType

defType x;
tdType y;
```

Here, the compiler sees variable x as an int, but variable y as a data type called 'tdType' that happens to be the same size as an int.  If you wrote a function that took a parameter of type defType, the caller could pass a normal int and the compiler wouldn't know the difference.  If the function instead took a parameter of type tdType, the compiler would ensure that a variable of the proper type was used during function calls.

Also, some debuggers have the ability to handle `typedef`s, which can be much more useful than having all custom types listed as their underlying primitive types (as it would be if `#define` was used instead).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, No.

`typedef` helps you set up an "alias" to an existing data type. For eg. `typedef char chr`;

`#define` is a **preprocessor** directive used to define macros or general pattern substitutions. For eg. `#define MAX 100`, substitutes all occurrences of `MAX` with 100

Answer (score 2):

No. 
[typedef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221152.aspx) is a C keyword that creates an alias for a type.
 #define is a pre-processor instruction, that creates a text replacement event prior to compilation. When the compiler gets to the code, the original "#defined" word is no longer there. #define is mostly used for macros and global constants.

Comment: The usage of the term "pointer" could lead to some confusion here.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I went back and added a link to typdef on MSDN - just in case anyone in the future will use this question to find what typedef is. But maybe I should change that word...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, there is a key difference between `#define` and typedef. The right way to think about that is to view a typedef as being a complete "encapsulated" type. It means that you cannot add to it after you have declared it.

You can extend a macro typename with other type specifiers, but not a typedef'd typename:

```
#define fruit int
unsigned fruit i;   // works fine

typedef int fruit;
unsigned fruit i;   // illegal
```

Also, a typedef'd name provides the type for every declator in a declaration.

```
#define fruit int *
fruit apple, banana;
```

After macro expansion, the second line becomes:

```
int *apple, banana;
```

Apple is a pointer to an int, while banana is an int. In comparison. a typedef like this:

```
typedef char *fruit;
fruit apple, banana;
```

declares both apple and banana to be the same. The name on the front is different, but they are both pointers to a char.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to use typedef (which has only been mentioned briefly in other answers and yet I think is the entire reason typedef was created) is to make debugging easier when using libraries that have custom types. For example, I'll use a type-conversion error. Both the codes below will print a compile-time error saying that a char is not comparable to a string, but in different ways.

```
typedef char letter;
letter el = 'e';
if(el == "hello");
```

The above code will print something like `the variable "el" of type letter (aka "char") is not compatable with type "char*"`

```
#define letter char
letter el = 'e';
if(el == "hello");
```

This code will instead print `the variable "el" of type char is not compatable with type "char*"`

This may seem silly because I'm defining "letter" as "char", but in more complex libraries this can be extremely confusing because pointers to objects like buttons, windows, sound servers, images, and lots of other things are defined as `unsigned char *`, which would only be debuggable as exactly that when using the #define method.

Answer (score -2):

As everyone said above, they aren't the same. Most of the answers indicate `typedef` to be more advantageous than `#define`.
But let me put a plus point of `#define` :
when your code is extremely big, scattered across many files, it's better to use `#define`; it helps in readability - you can simply preprocess all the code to see the actual type definition of a variable at the place of its declaration itself.