# What does preprocessing exactly mean in compiler

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the difference between a typedef and define. There are a lot of good posts specially at [this previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c), however I can't understand the post that states

> `#define` is a preprocessor token: the compiler itself will never see it.
>     `typedef` is a compiler token: the preprocessor does not care about it.

Could anyone please explain this with a little more detail. I am confused with the term preprocessor here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pre-processor is a program that runs *before* the compiler and essentially performs text substitution.  When you write:

```
#define X 10

int main() 
{
    int x = X;
}
```

The pre-processor take that file as input, does it's thing, and outputs:

```
int main() 
{
    int x = 10;
}
```

And then the compiler does its thing with the pre-processed output.

`typedef` on the other hand is a construct that the compiler understands.  When you write:

```
typedef unsigned int uint_32;
```

The compiler knows that `uint32` is actually an alias for `unsigned int`.  This alias is handled by the compiler itself and involves a bit more logic than simple text substitution.  This becomes obvious with a simple example:

```
typedef int my_int;

int main()
{
    unsigned my_int x;  // oops, error
}
```

If a `typedef` were a simple text substitution mechanism (like the pre-processor is) then that would work, but it is not allowed and will fail to compile.

Answer (score 5):

A preprocessor is a phase that occurs BEFORE any compilation starts. It reads specific macros and symbols to substitute. Its usually one to two pass. It scans the whole source file, and generates a symbol table to substitute or expand macros.

After all the substitutions are done, the syntax analyzer takes over lexing-parsing the source file, generating abstract syntax trees, generating code, linking libraries and generating executables/binaries.

In C/C++/ObjC Preprocessor DIRECTIVES start with '#' followed by the directive name such as "define", "ifdef", "ifndef", "elif", "if", "endif" etc.

BEFORE PREPROCESSING:

```
#define TEXT_MACRO(x) L##x
#define RETURN return(0)   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static wchar_t buffer[] = TEXT_MACRO("HELLO WORLD");
    RETURN ;
}
```

AFTER PREPROCESSING:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static wchar_t buffer[] = L"HELLO WORLD";
    return (0);
}
```

If I remember correctly, the book "The C Programming Language" 2nd Edition, by Kernighan and Ritchie has an example, where they show how to create your own PREPROCESSOR and HOW IT WORKS. Also the Plan9 C Compiler separated the two processes(compilation and preprocessing). Allowing you to use your own PREPROCESSOR in it.

Check out [An interesting preprocessor for multiple languages](http://code.google.com/p/preprocess/) and [Write your own pre-processor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3853/Wave-a-Standard-conformant-C-preprocessor-library). Seeing the input and output of these programs gives you a deeper understanding of what a preprocessor actually is.

Another little secret: You can code C in latin/german/spanish if you have a preprocessor :)

Comment: +1 Correct answer and you gave it first. An example would be nice, though.

Comment: An example would have been nice

Comment: @chris didn't notice. THanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The C and C++ preprocessors are a logical phase in the compilation that occurs very early on.  The preprocessor converts a source file into a translation unit by including the text of header files that are specified by `#include`, by conditionally eliminating parts of the files (`#if`, `#elif`, `#else`, `#endif`, and variants `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`), and by doing macro substitutions.  The macros are defined via `#define`; the macros can be detected by the preprocessor scanning the source.

The preprocessor eliminates most lines that start with `#` (it only leaves `#line` directives behind and its own abbreviated variants on `#line` behind to tell the compiler where the source came from).  The compiler proper then sees the result of the pre-processing and compiles the source code that is defined.

The preprocessor would not normally modify the word `typedef`.  An insane programmer could define a macro for `typedef` and the preprocessor might not care; the programmer could not legitimately include any system header while there is a macro defined with the same name as any keyword in the language.  Otherwise, though, `typedef` is a problem for the compiler, not the preprocessor.  So, too, is `sizeof()`; that is not something the preprocessor understands.

There are usually compiler options to allow you to see the pre-processed output.  For `gcc`, the options are `-E` and `-P`.

Comment: +1: @Jonathn Leffler,  I came here trying to understand what was mean by compiler proper in the man pages and you answered it.

Comment: Re “it only leaves `#line` directives behind”: That is some internal behavior of a C implementation. If any preprocessor (standalone or built into the compiler) leaves `#line` directives behind, then preprocessing as specified by the C standard is not yet complete, and the compiler (conceptually at least) still has to complete preprocessing by removing them. Within the translation model specified by the C standard, `#line` directives cannot be left behind because they cannot be parsed by the lexical grammar.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to compilation, your source code pass through a lot of step. In those step, there is pre-proccessing.

The preprocessor is program that runs before the compiler, and execute all the `#` started instructions, like `#include`, `#define`, etc..

In your particular case, `#define WORD newword` is a directive that says : "Replace all occurrence of WORD with newword", before even trying to compile the program.

If you want to see it in action, try to run `cpp file.c` and examine the output to understand what it does.

file.c

```
 #define WORD "newword"

 int main()
 {
     printf("this is word: %s\n", WORD);
     return 0;                           
 }
```

will become after cpp runs

```
int main()
{
    printf("this is word: %s\n", "newword");
    return 0;
}
```

---

typedef, on the other hand, are used to say "if I talk about `Type`, understand that I meant `struct more_complex_type`" It is used at compile time, and will stay the same before and after the `cpp` pass.

Answer (score 2):

A preprocessor is an "engine" executed before the compiler compiles code. 
`#define #include` are preprocessor directives or macros, so the preprocessor engine executes code related  to the directives. When the preprocessor is done the compiler sees nothing of the directives/macros. 
However constructs such as `typedef`, `if`, `while` etc.. are understood by the compiler.

Comment: In visual studio when we write code does the preprocessor run while we are typing (ie after we have declared a preprocessor and might attempt to use it)?

Comment: It would make sense if it does. Otherwise the intellisense would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the preprocessor runs before the compiler and it modifies the source code before passing it on to the compiler. Thus, the compiler never sees some of the code. Example:

```
#define ONE 1
int x = ONE;
```

When you compile this, the preprocessor changes it into this:

```
int x = 1;
```

and passes that new text to the compiler. Thus, the compiler does not see the text `ONE`.