# How to generate namespace dynamically based on the config key

Tags: c#, namespaces

In Azure function app based on settings value, I want to switch namespace.
For example

```
#if System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) == "true" 
namespace TestA
#else
namespace TestB
#endif
```

Please help me on this. If you have other approaches other than this example please suggest me

Comment: It seems like you do not really know basics of [preprocessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982106/what-does-preprocessing-exactly-mean-in-compiler).

Comment: @m.rogalski:  Do you have any idea of achieving the namespace switching based on the key value?

Comment: If you want to switch it at runtime then, no. There's no way other than recompiling that code over and over again when the value is changing. And even then you would have to make some background check every few seconds to get the actual value and recompile that piece of code.

Comment: @m.rogalski: Thanks for the information