# Can I name a variable with the same name as a typedef'd structure name?

Tags: c, gcc

Here is the structure declare code.

```
struct list_el {
    int val;
    struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;
```

And when I write a function like this, the compiler gives a error. It says `cur undeclared before first use`.

```
bool delete(item* item)
{
    assert(item != NULL);

    item* cur = NULL;
    cur = head;
    item* prev = NULL;
    while (cur) {
        if (cur == item) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                head = item->next;
            } else {
                prev->next = item->next;
            }
            free(item);
            return true;
        }

        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After I look up the reference, it says the `typedef` works <s>out just</s> a bit like `#define`. It simply makes a substitution at compile time.  Is that the reason the code can't be compiled?

Comment: `typedef` doesn't work like `#define`. which reference said so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this code:

```
bool delete(item* item)
{
    item *cur = NULL;
```

the `item` in the third line is taken to be the name of the variable `item` (the parameter to the function), and not the type.  Consequently, the third line looks as if it starts out as an expression that multiplies `item` by the undefined variable `cur`, which leads to problems; the rest of the expression is also bogus.

If this isn't what you want, don't use the same name for a type and a variable.  You'll confuse other people even if you don't confuse yourself and the compiler.

---

Whichever reference source said that `typedef` and `#define` are 'the same' should be dropped from your list of references *now*!  If it can't differentiate two such fundamentally different constructs, it is dangerous because you won't know when it is misleading you (but this is one case where it is misleading you).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler `(item* item)` will create compilation error?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: It doesn't cause a compilation error under GCC. I'm a little surprised. I think it comes down to scope. There's a new scope with the function definition, and in that scope, the plain name `item` now means the variable. I'm not certain that's how you scrape by, but it looks semi-plausible.  You can see it with: `int x = 0; int func(void) { int y = x; int x = y + 1; ... }` which is legitimate. The first `x` in the function is the global variable; the second is a new local variable that shadows the global. The situation in the function in the question is similar, I hypothesize.

Comment: You are correct, I also checked it myself, And yes due to scope ...also its correct in C but not in Java. : Thanks

Comment: You changed your answer!...you wrote something about c99 and c89

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I gave an answer to a different problem (and mentioned C89 vs C99).  The compiler is stipulated by the tags to be GCC; I was thinking it might be MSVC, in which case `assert()` could not precede a declaration.  However, the problem starts before that, and the complaint wasn't about a variable definition appearing where it isn't allowed but about the absence of a variable definition.

Comment: hi, @JonathanLeffler, gcc will give you a warning if you use `gcc -Wshadow`. Just like my answer in this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Jonathan Leffler. The book says it like #define but not the same, my mistake. But i am kind of curious about how do you get the reason that the compiler look the item in item *cur as the first parameter. Have you read the source code of gcc? I am not suspecting your answer, just curious.

Comment: Basically, because of the error it generated.  If it was still treating `item` as a type name, it would be a variable definition (of `cur`).  (The code is missing a declaration for `head`, incidentally.)  So it was the mere fact that you got the error that tipped me off to what was going on.  As I said in an earlier comment, I was a little surprised that the function definition line compiled, but GCC (tested: 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5) is quite happy with it, leaving the conclusion I came to as the logical answer to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A typedef is just a new name for an already existing type. defines are handled by the  preprocessor while typedefs are handled by the C compiler itself. [copied from this [link]](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/634947-difference-between-typedef-define-c)

check this question: [Are typedef and #define the same in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c)

Comment: Moreover, forcing the compiler to guess from context whether you were referring to an instance of object, or the type name is at the very least a pathetic approach and should not be allowed by the compiler. A little insane example   typedef int b; double b;  b = 4; - compilation error

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is not completely same as `#define`

Here is the difference by example:

```
#define cptr1 char*

typedef char* cptr2;
```

In code:

```
           int main()
            {
             cptr1 c1,c2; // first case : 
        // here c1 will be pointer to char but c2 is only char as cptr 
   // is directly replaced by char* by preprocessor
            cptr2 c3,c4; // second case :
      // here c3 and c4 both are pointers to char 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `-Wshadow` when you compile you code. 
Then, gcc will tell you where you are wrong. :-)
like follows:
     `declaration of ‘item’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]`

Comment: Since i am a newbie to c programming, so should i open as many as warning options in `gcc` as possible?

Comment: @user674199, I think so. you will avoid lots of mistake if you open them. And they will save your debuging time.   :-)

Comment: If you're compiling with GCC, as you are, then using `-Wall` will save you from a lot of problems.  I use some extra options too — sometimes, but not always, including `-Wshadow`.  Because of the retrograde and archaic code I work with, I find `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` useful. I compile with `-Wextra` when I can, but that is a demanding standard of coding; I'd forgive some warnings under `-Wextra` (but very few of the warnings under the other options).  Using `-Werror` keeps you honest, too.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Leffler answered you your question.

I just want to add: if you write your code in c++, you don't need to typedef, so you can implement your list just like this:

```
struct list_el {
    int val;
    list_el *next;
};

bool delete_element(list_el *item)
{
    list_el *cur = NULL;
    ...
}
```