# C struct with same type name as variable name?

Tags: c++, c, gnu99

I am working on a project where there is a .h file that contains the following lines:

File1.h

```
typedef struct {
int a; 
} MyData;

typedef struct {
  MyData MyData;
} MyDataContainer;
```

This is compiled using gnu99 standard without any issues. However, if i include File1.h in a C++ file compiled using gcc standard gnu++17, i get errors related to the type name MyData and the instance MyData having the same name. I am not really used to working in C. Is there a reason to have the same type name as the instance name? I cannot change the C file, are there workarounds to #include File1.h in a C++ file?

Thank you in advance for your help.

File1.h compiles with no errors. When i link the library compiled using gnu99 in a library compiled in C++, it throws errors.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules about the namespaces of struct, variable, etc. names.

Comment: I understand, I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this when i call C code from C++. Unfortunately it's not possible to go back and modify the C code.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Yes but the code within `extern "C" { ... }` is still C++ code. For example, `int class;` is still a syntax error.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük `extern "C"` only affects the linkage of functions.

Comment: No it won't solve OP's issue

Comment: What are the exact errors you get when you compile a C++ file including the "C" header file? Also be very precise  in the types you show not just some made up "Type1" types.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide [mcve]

Comment: *i get errors related to the type name MyData and the instance MyData having the same name* Don't retell the error message. Post the verbatim error with a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like the reason is pesky `typedef struct` construct - yet another reason to avoid it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer the made up types that i wrote as Type1 are custom types similar to "MyData". I received the following errors: "error: declaration of ‘MyData <unnamed struct>::MyData ’ changes meaning of ‘MyData ’ [-fpermissive]"

Comment: @yayatorree Maybe the `C` file was meant to be used in a `C` module, not C++.  Otherwise contact the authors of this header file -- either they will change it, or they will tell you "it wasn't meant for C++".

Comment: As described in [mcve] you should remove unrelated details like `Type1` and make sure your code is minimal and still shows the problem. Currently your code fails to compile due to unrelated issues - like `Type1` is undefined

Comment: @yayatorree *When i link the library compiled using gnu99 in a library compiled in C++, it throws errors.* -- The error you posted in the previous comment is not a linker error.  It is a compile error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah, thats reasonable.

Comment: Looks like unlike `struct` name `typedef` name conflicts with variable name.

Comment: See GCC's [`-Wno-changes-meaning` documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  I think that option was only introduced in GCC 13 though, which is still quite new.  You can use `-fpermissive` or `-fms-extensions` on older GCC.  MSVC and Clang both permit the code in the question.

Comment: @yayatorree -- This was quite common when C++ first became popular back in the late 80's and early 90's.  `C` headers were designed for `C` programs only, not C++.  Thus usage of these headers in a C++ program were either not possible, or required editing by either the author or the programmer to get it to be compatible with C++.

Comment: If I use `struct foobar {}; foobar foobar;` it compiles fine. But if I try to use `foobar foobar` in another struct (typedefed or not) then it fails. Interesting

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie interesting, the c code is indeed fairly old, maybe early 2000s

Comment: The root problem is that C has different namespaces for ordinary identifiers (like ones from `typedef`), struct tags and struct members. So `typedef struct MyData { MyData MyData; } NoImagination;` is valid C. You might find this interesting: [Are there technical reasons to pick one struct coding style over the other?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/290881)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Preamble:* In C++, the code in the question is ill-formed, no diagnostic required; see [Variable with same name as type - which compiler is right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450095) for Standard references.

---

If you cannot modify the C file then there are no seamless, well-defined workarounds .

It may be possible to disable the error message, in which case the behaviour of the program will be formally undefined, but is likely to work correctly:

- in g++ 13, use `-Wno-changes-meaning`.
- use `-fms-extensions`, but that has [other effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554567/).

---

Failing that, you will have to make an intermediate layer between the C code and the C++ code, with a new function to wrap every C function the C++ code needed to call with a MyData argument; for example:

```
// MyKludge.h
typedef struct {
  Type1 myVar1;
  Type2 myVar2;
} MyData;

typedef struct {
    MyData foo;
    TypeA myVarA; 
    TypeB myVarB; 
} MyDataContainer2; 

void File1Func(MyDataContainer2 *x);

// MyKludge.c
#include "File1.h"
#include "MyKludge.h"

void File1FuncWrapper (MyDataContainer2 *x)
{
    // Technically undefined behaviour but will probably work
    File1Func( (MyDataContainer *)x );

    // Definitely well-defined but could be inefficient depending on compiler
    MyDataContainer y;
    y.MyData = x->foo;
    y.MyVarA = x->MyVarA;
    y.MyVarB = x->MyVarB;
    File1Func( &y );
    x->foo = y.MyData;   // If func might change object
    x->MyVarA = y.MyVarA;
    x->MyVarB = y.MyVarB;
}
```

Comment: is the code in question legal when using a standard newer than gnu99 and compiling with C? also, it sounds like the main solution proposed by several folks on here is to ask the developers to change the code, and workarounds not preferable especially if causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @yayatorree The code in the question has always been legal in C

Comment: If you're amenable to punning types, isn't it easier to copy the header, modify the member names and link with other TUs as if the struct is the same? AFAIK struct ABI doesn't depend on member names.

Comment: @PasserBy that may cause link errors, the compiler will assign a struct tag to each struct and it might give a different one to the two structs in question since they are not lexically identical.  The linker will identify struct pointers in function parameters by their struct tags, not typedef names