# typedef vs #define for datatypes in c

Tags: c, macros, typedef

A few months ago during an interview, I was asked how to go about implementing a boolean datatype in C.  The two most common ways would to either be:

Preprocessor Macros:

```
#define BOOL unsigned char
```

Or typedefs:

```
typedef BOOL unsigned char;
```

So I was wondering what the exact benefits and trade-offs of using either preprocessor macros or typedefs are?  I commonly find myself making datatypes like "uint16," (for unsigned shorts) and "ucharp," (for unsigned char pointers).  Which would be best to use?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/is-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c?rq=1

Comment: How about `typedef enum BOOL { false, true };`?

Comment: C already has a boolean type, `_Bool` (since C99 anyway...).

Comment: `uint16` already exists, with the name `uint16_t`, in <stdint.h>` (since C99). And typedefs for pointer types are generally not a great idea; I prefer just to use `unsigned char*`.

Comment: `typedef BOOL unsigned char;` -- wrong. `ucharp` -- what possible advantage does that have over `uchar*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural answer is defining an enumerated type:

```
typedef enum {false = 0, true} BOOL;
```

It is **important** to note, however, that this `BOOL` type we have declared behaves a little bit differently than the C99 `_Bool` type (most commonly used through the `bool` macro defined in `stdbool.h`).

For example:

```
int main(void) {
    BOOL B;  // our type
    bool b;  // the type from C99

    B = -true; // -1
    b = -true; // 1

    B = true + true;  // 2
    b = true + true;  // 1

    return 0;
}
```

The C99 `bool` acts according to the rules of [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), while our make-do `BOOL` acts just like a regular `int`. This is due to the fact that a variable of type `enum` is actually an `int`.

If you're using C99, there's absolutely no valid reason on this Earth to roll your own type rather than just use the `bool` defined in `stdbool.h`.

If you're on an earlier standard, a typedef'd `enum` is as good as it gets, unfortunately.

Comment: The difference only shows up on operations that no sane person would perform on Booleans.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That is true, if you consider that boolean arithmetic is for those who are insane :-)

Comment: @dranov - most programmers would.