# Rename arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, alias

I would like to know if it is possible to give arrays in c aliases. My first try was this:

```
#define string char[]
```

But of course this does not work because array in c are defines like this:

```
 char test[] = ""; //Correct
 char[] test = ""; //Wrong
```

Do you know a workaround to this or is this not possible in standard c?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `typedef`.

```
typedef char string[];
string a = "abcd";
```

However, it is far from perfect. You cannot use it without an initializer when defining a variable. The following won't work.

```
string b;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will do some more deep research and tests to maybe get something stabler.

Comment: @HeinZi, you are welcome. Best of luck with your work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @RSahu's answer, using `#define` for types is dangerous.  For example:

```
#define STRING char *
STRING a, b;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c) for more details.