# complicated Typedef in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

I understand that typedef can be used to define a new custom type, for example:

```
// simple typedef
typedef unsigned long ulong;

// the following two objects have the same type 
unsigned long l1;
ulong l2;
```

I recently came across this typedef, and got lost in deciphering what is going on in the declaration:

```
typedef int16_t CALL_CONVENTION(* product_init_t)(product_descript_t *const description)
```

Can someone guide me and explain what this is doing?

EDIT: changed NEW_TYPE to CALL_CONVENTION. It's a define. Thanks for spotting that out.

Comment: It declares a function pointer type alias. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer.

Comment: I'd rather say `typedef int16_t (* stuff)(stuff) NEW_TYPE;`

Comment: What is `NEW_TYPE`? is that a `#define`?

Comment: typedefs dont define a new type, they just provide you an alias for an already existing type

Comment: Use [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) to decode complex type declarations.

Comment: @ForceBru: could you please explain what effect (* stuff)(stuff) has on int16_t. That is, what difference would it make to have only typedef int16_t  NEW_TYPE; ?

Comment: @GregHewgill NEW_TYPE is not a define. It's the 'newly'  created alias.

Comment: @ForceBru that would be a syntax error

Comment: @nikk no, `product_init_t` is what's being declared here

Comment: Correction, NEW_TYPE is a "define". Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @Barmar i get a syntax error for this one on cdecl

Comment: Probably because of the `CALL_CONVENTION` macro, since cdecl has no way of knowing that that does. You need to expand the macro first.

Comment: @Barmar @tobi303,  example
`ifdef __amd64__
          define CALL_CONVENTION
      else           define CALL_CONVENTION   __attribute__((__cdecl__))       endif`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It declares type `product_init_t` as a pointer to a function which

- takes parameter `product_descript_t *const description`;
- returns `int16_t`;
- uses calling convention `CALL_CONVENTION` (as **@M.M** suggested even when it was misnamed).

---

**P.S.** Since "*a complete answer in 2016 should show the modern way to write this `type-alias`*" (**@Howard Hinnant**), here it is:

```
using product_init_t = int16_t (CALL_CONVENTION *)(product_descript_t *const description);
```

Comment: it's likely that `NEW_TYPE` is a linkage or calling convention specifier; not a part of the return type

Comment: @M.M  Likely, but then the name is somewhat confusing. Anyway, added to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @M.M you are right. I have made the edit to the post.

Comment: Ok thanks. This CLEARLY helps me understand the problem. Accepting as answer. One last thing, I am fairly new to compiler infrastructure, so if you an point me to a web link on dealing with Calling Conventions for these type of statements, I'll truly appreciate it.

Comment: A complete answer in 2016 should show the modern way to write this *type-alias* which imho is much cleaner.

Comment: @HowardHinnant As you wish :).

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to make sense of complicated typedefs: First look at the line with `typedef` taken out:

```
int16_t NEW_TYPE (* product_init_t)(product_descript_t *const description);
```

Then work out what this line would declare: it's a variable called `product_init_t` with a certain type.

Finally, adding `typedef` means that it declares `product_init_t` to be an alias for that certain type, instead of a variable of that type.

---

To work out the above declaration, you can use `cdecl` , or you can attack it from the outside-in using knowledge of the possible declarators (pointer, array, function).

In this case the outer-most feature is the parameter list at the right, so we suspect this might be a function declarator.  Function declarators look like (roughly):

```
returntype    function_name   (parameters_opt)
```

although bear in mind that a common compiler extension is to specify additonal properties of the function via `__declspec` or otherwise, in the same place as the return type; or there might be `extern "C"` there, and so on.

So far we are at the stage that `(*product_init_t)` is a function with `int16_t NEW_TYPE` as return type (and possible declspecs), and parameter list `(product_descript_t *const description)`.

Finally, `* product_init_t` is just a pointer declarator, so we conclude that `product_init_t` is a pointer to a function of the above type.

Your comments indicate being unsure about `NEW_TYPE`. It will be something that is already defined earlier (or a compiler extension keyword); perhaps preprocessing the code with `gcc -E` would help if your IDE can't find its definition.

Comment: The correct line is `typedef int16_t CALL_CONVENTION(* product_init_t)(product_descript_t *const description)`

where CALL CONVENTION is defined in 
`ifdef __amd64__ define CALL_CONVENTION else define CALL_CONVENTION __attribute__((__cdecl__)) endif`

how will this now make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting example of difference between `#define` and `typedef` usage.

```
#define FX_TYPE void (*)(int)
typedef void (*stdfx)(int);

void fx_typ(stdfx fx); /* ok */
void fx_def(FX_TYPE fx); /* error */
```

please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c)

Therefore in case of following:

```
typedef int16_t CALL_CONVENTION(* product_init_t)(product_descript_t *const description)
```

We can use the above typedef as follows:

```
void fx_typ(product_init_t fx);
```

`fx` is a pointer to function which takes `product_descript_t *const description` as argument and returns `int16_t`.

The use of  CALL_CONVENTION is confusing, however, it can be suppressed by empty macro as follows:

```
#define  CALL_CONVENTION
```

Note: the above micro has no body. In my view, `CALL_CONVENTION` just adds to confusion.

Comment: Good point, @vivek. CALL CONVENTION is actually defined as empty (for the most part) in my example. I wonder what is the point.