# How to define types from qmake? Preinclude header file?

Tags: c++, qt, typedef, qmake

I am reusing some structures from c project. That project uses auto/preincluded header with some type definitions. That means that there is no call:

```
#include "architecture.h"
```

in the related source files.

I am trying fix this with defining types from qt pri file:

```
DEFINES += int8_t="\"signed char\""
DEFINES += uint8_t="\"unsigned char\""
DEFINES += int16_t="\"signed int\""
DEFINES += uint16_t="\"unsigned int\""
DEFINES += int32_t="\"signed long int\""
DEFINES += uint32_t="\"unsigned long int\""
```

I get compiler errors "duplicate signed", "multiple types in one declaration",...

There is somethin about the types and defines at [typedef vs define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c).

Is there a better way to solve this case with auto include?
How to fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to create duplicates of types already in [the standard `<cstdint>` header file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)?

Comment: Because that is not included in some sources I would like to use. Those types are target related and defined by the "architecture.h" that is auto included in the base project of an embeded device. But I do not know the way to force such a include in the qt project using qmake.

Comment: If you're using GCC (or Clang) then you can use the `-include` option to forcibly include a header file from the build command line. Read [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for more information.

Comment: Thats a good hint for those compilers. I am using MinGW. It may go with setting it as QMAKE_CXXFLAGS.

Comment: I have added a line: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -include path/to/architecture.h` to my qmake pro file and with that forced include of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DEFINES +- xyz_t="...."` colides with typedefinitions of qt included system headers like `<cstdint>` used by Qt Objects.

gcc compatible compiler ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), MinGW, clang) have option `-include <file>` to force preinclude.

In qmake this can be used by [QMAKE_CXXFLAGS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -include path/to/file.h
```

In the included `file.h` we can include other system type definition headers like:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cstddef>
```

This way types are well and safely defined.

Comment: The equivalent Visual Studio compiler option is [`/FI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx).