# Curiosity about preprocessor directive with #define

Tags: c

I am practicing on `#define` and `typedef`. I think I got a good hold on the matter, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c) valid discussion. 
Currently, I am on this simple chunk of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*typedef char *string;       with typedef the code works correctly*/

#define string char *

int main(void){
    string a[] = {"I", "like", "to", "fight,"}, 
           b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",
        a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b[0], b[1], b[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `define` gives directive to the preprocessor. In this case, to substitute `string` with `char *`. Because of that, `a` is correctly declared as `char *a[]`, while `b[]` is not! 
The problem could easily be addressed with

```
string b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};
```

but my [textbook](https://www.amazon.it/Book-C-Programming/dp/B00BG733WS/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1526138568&sr=8-4&keywords=kelley%20pohl%20c) challenge the reader by telling that the code with `#define` can work just by precisely **adding** **one** single character. I have been unable to figure out the solution. It is just for the sake of curiosity that I propose this simple problem to the community. Hence, thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: And that's why we generally don't use macros, or want anyone to be clever and use macros. C's declaration syntax is complicated, and not easily amenable to textual substitution.

Comment: Add a character to the `#define`, or to `main`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I mainly agree. As far as my brief experience can tell, macros are more subtle to use.

Comment: @aschepler That is not specified, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `*` before `b` will make the code work because then it expands to:

```
char *a[] = {"I", "like", "to", "fight,"}, 
     *b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};
```

Of course having the `*` there will look utterly confusing when using the `string` macro (making it look like `b` is an array of `string` pointers), which I imagine is the point of the exercise: to show why using macros as a poor man's `typedef` leads to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

This is why you should not use macro, after replacement you will get:

```
char* a[] = {"I", "like", "to", "fight,"}, 
       b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};
```

where a is array of pointers to chars, and b is array of chars.

This is how declaration work, counter example:

```
char* a, b;
```

a is pointer to char b is char, to make it so you would have to write:

```
char* a, *b;
```

Comment: BTW even using `typedef char *string;`  is questionable. It make believe that there _is_ a `string` type, but `string` is still a mere pointer to char.

Answer (score 3):

After preprocessing, your code will look like this:

```
char * a[] = {"I", "like", "to", "fight,"}, 
       b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};
```

In this way, `b` will be an array of `char`.

To solve the issue:

```
string a[] = {"I", "like", "to", "fight,"}, 
       *b[] = {"pinch", "and", "bight."};
       ^
       You have to add an asterisk here.
```